# Does $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2x}{k^2-x^2}$ converges [uniformly] on any interval having no integers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to know whether the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2x}{k^2-x^2}$ converges uniformly on any interval $[a,b]$ that contains no integers. 
Intuitively, I think the answer is yes. 
But I have no idea with how to prove it rigorously. 
I thought it would be much better to use partial fraction to express the series as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{k-x} - \frac{1}{k+x} \right)$, but it gives nothing to me.
Could you help me?

Comment: You could show that it is normally convergent. For that you only need to show that there exists some constant $C>0$ such that for all natural numbers $k$ holds $$ \sup_{x\in [a,b]} \left\vert \frac{2x}{k^2-x^2} \right\vert \leq \frac{C}{k^2}. $$

Comment: Split the sum into $\sum_{k=0}^N +  \sum_{k=N}^\infty$ where $N$ is chosen sufficiently large such that the second sum behaves like $\sum_{k=N}^\infty 1/k^2$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Can you give me a little bit more hints? I know the boundary is |2a/k^2-a^2|, but cannot show it is less than C/k^2.

Comment: You have $\vert x \vert \leq \max\{ \vert a \vert, \vert b \vert \}$. Then we can pick $N$ sufficiently large such that for $k\geq N$ we have $k^2 \geq 2x^2$ for all $x\in [a,b]$. I guess you can take it from here?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Umm...unfortunately, I am struggling at that part.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Is it C=4a?

Comment: For an open interval with integer end point, convergence will not be uniform.